# How to generate pdf from a libreoffice calc sheet fitting the page width?

Tags: pdf, libreoffice-calc

Using LibreOffice 4.1.2.3 in Ubuntu 13.10 I am desperately trying to export the content of a sheet (4 columns) into a pdf (portrait), so all 4 columns fit on a page. A [page](https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Export_as_PDF#Fit_width) nicely explains all the settings - but they do not have any effect!

I select all the range I want to export to a pdf (the 4 columns previously mentioned), click File -> Export as PDF, and no matter what I change (e.g. zoom to 7%), the generated pdf  contains two pages: One page with the first three columns, and another page with the fourth column.

This is quite cumbersome and ridiculous, and any help is appreciated to solve this problem.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/668040/how-to-scale-a-long-libreoffice-calc-sheet-to-fit-on-two-pages-when-exporting-to

Comment: This has nothing to do with StackOverflow.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Maybe the LibreOffice Help is misleading here. Those settings (Fit width etc) just affect how to **display the resulting PDF**. If you want to **scale the output** to make it fit to a certain number of pages, you will have to **modify the [page styles's properties](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Sheet_2#Scale)**: Menu **`Format`** -> **`Page...`** -> **`Sheet Tab`**.

[image: Fit Width]

Here, you have three options:

- **`Reduce / enlarge printout`**: set a fixed scaling factor (e.g. `50 %`);
- **`Fit print range(s) to width / heigth`**: set either the maximum width or maximum heigth in pages, scaling will be proportionally in every case;
- **`Fit print range(s) on number of pages`**: set the maximum page number.

In your case, just select the third option and set the page number to **`1`**:

[image: Fit to page number]

Answer (score 6):

Go to File > Print Preview, and adjust the content size with the zoom slider. Click Export and you're done.

Comment: Nice and easy trick, worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same settings as in tohuwawohu's answer, though page still ended too early after column EF, no matter of Scale, Page width or margin settings. 
Then I discovered `Format -> Print Ranges -> Edit` menu  with custom range - [image: img].

Changing to last column solved my problem. HTH somebody.